# Complex sorting in Magento collections

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, zend-db, magento-1.5

I need to add a fairly complex sorting option to the product collection in Magento and I'm just not that good with the Zend framework or EAV tables to figure out what I need to do to make this work.  I'd like to be able to sort the product collection by gross margin, taking into account shipping costs.  `cost` is a Magento attribute, stored in the `catalog_product_entity_decimal` table.  Shipping cost is stored as `actual_shipping_cost` in the `catalog_product_entity_varchar` table.  Somehow, I need to add a column to the SQL select statement on which I can sort.  This column needs to contain the `cost` from `c_p_e_decimal` *minus* `actual_shipping_cost` from `c_p_e_varchar`.

I have my own classes that extend `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List`, `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar`, and `Mage_Catalog_Model_Config`.  These work together to add the necessary sort option to the available sort-by array.  Inside my custom `List` class, I check `getCurrentOrder()` on the toolbar instance.  If it is *margin* I need to add the column with the necessary values and apply the sorting.

So, I've gotten that far, but it's constructing the proper `Zend_Db_Expr` that has me confused.  I'm not an expert on Joins, Unions, and all things SQL, nor do I have a strong grasp of the Zend Framework, so please forgive my ignorance.  I've been reading up on the Zend Framework and I now mostly understand what I'm looking at when I find examples, but constructing my own from scratch is still a bit beyond me.  So any guidance would be REALLY helpful!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well if you need to sort your fields by margins then you are looking values from wrong places as you only know the margin after the sale and shipping costs also after the user has entered the address and so on. So your best approach would be to go over completed orders and items in each order  and shipping cost over each order and write the margin value to some attribute in your product collection, later filter like any other attribute.